# Any content inside section adds 1em margin on right side, how to remove it?

Tags: html, css

any content that I add inside a  overrides the css reset and adds a 1em margin on the right side on the website (the bottom bar doesn't show but if you click with the mouse wheel you can slide it to the side).

```css
/*Reset*/
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    
}
p {
    margin:0;
    margin-block-end: 0;
    margin-block-start: 0;
}

header{
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

section.sec1{
    display: block;
    background-image: url('assets/bg1.avif');
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

section.sec2{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

section.sec3{
    background-color: green;
}

section.sec4{
    background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>html page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <p>header</p>
    </header>

    <section class="sec1">
        <p>sec1</p>
    </section>
    
    <section class="sec2">
        <p>sec2</p>
    </section>

    <section class="sec3">
        <p>sec3</p>
    </section>

    <section class="sec4">
        <p>sec4</p>
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

How can i solve this issue? Thank you.

PS: the "bg1.avif" is 2158 x 1798px, but even without it you can see the problem.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue. All `margin-block-end & start` are at `0` in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use width:100vw on html, body and section elements.

But if you want to, use *'width:100%;'* instead of *'width:100vw;'*